# "give someone a workout" or "give someone a training"?

Tags: word-choice

Let us say a new gym member wants a gym coach to train for the first. So what would be correct:

> The coach agreed to give the client a workout.
>
> The coach agreed to give the client a training.

Tell me please what is the natural way say that!

Comment: To use "train", it would be simpler to say, "The coach agreed to **train** the client."

Comment: @fixer1234: Or if you wanted to be clear that this was a one time thing, something like "The coach agreed to give the client an initial training session."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first sentence (**workout**) would be fine if the workout is a single training session.

If you look up **training** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/training), you will see that it says noun U: the U means that it is uncountable. With uncountable nouns, you don't use the indefinite article **a**, so your second sentence is incorrect as it stands.

If you want to talk about a single session, you could say **a training session**. If the training might over several sessions, you could say **some training**.

Comment: Yes, a training session, or a workout.

Comment: “To give someone a workout” maybe should be avoided because that specific choice of words can have another (slang - sexual) meaning.

Comment: @James Well, yes,but here it is OK I would think. To oversee a workout. To help with a workout.

Comment: Agree with @Lambie in this context it’s fine, just be aware of the other meaning.

Answer (score 3):

We don't normally say **a training** since it is non-count, but **a training session** or simply **training**.

Comment: Would you actually say "The coach agreed to give the client training."?

Comment: @JavaLatte: I think in OP's context (judging from earlier questions asked) the coach is an exercise coach, and in that context I don't see anything amiss with *The coach agreed to give the client training* but I'm not sure of the exact context. Perhaps *The coach agreed to give the prospective client a free introductory training session.*

Comment: We never say "a training" in any event.